# Tweepy search query issues

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm working on a program to analyse data using Twitter's REST API, I looking to use a query with multiple keywords to get the results I'm looking for. However, I'm having issues when using a search query to get specific results. I have followed the documentation to use 'OR' search for multiple words but it's only working to a certain extent.

In this code when I use the query:

```
q = ('plane fly OR car drive -filter:retweets AND filter:replies')
```

It returns tweets that either include the words 'plane' & 'fly' OR 'car' & 'drive'. But if I added another keyword filter on at random, for example:

```
q = ('plane fly OR car drive OR cadburys chocolate -filter:retweets AND filter:replies')
```

This does not return any tweets at all. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the way the query works with the use of OR, but I'd imagine even if there were no tweets containing 'cadburys chocolate', it would still return the other tweets for the other keywords?

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? If the query can be structured this way? Or if not, is there a way I can search for multiple keywords/phrases in one query?

Thanks for you time, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be fine. Could you try use AND instead of space when using multiple comparison (more than two).
q = ('plane AND fly OR car AND drive OR cadburys AND chocolate -filter:retweets AND filter:replies')

You may need to use the AND operator when stringing multiple operators together.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried the query you recommended and it still return nothing. It's strange that it worked fine for 'plane fly OR car drive' but stopped as soon as I added another?

Comment: There might be another possibility of not having any tweets with them all. I suggest you to check with the results you got from your first query. "plane fly OR car drive"

Take keywords from this answer and add an extra "AND" comparison. If you are unclear what I meant could you please share 2-3 results from your first query.?

Comment: I think I understand, it might looking for tweets with a word from each of the keywords? I've ran my code again and the results I've got seem to suggest that...  

1) "Snow storm this morning. Hour and a half car ride to the airport. 6 hours on the plane and an hour and a half drive…"

2) "In my country we say to let a woman drive a car is like to let a monkey fly a plane, very dangerous yes."

3)"tbh wish I could drive my car as fast as a plane... they go 502 mph..?"

Is there a way to get results for tweets that ONLY contain 'plane/fly' OR 'car/drive' and not a combination of both?

Comment: I reckon you should get some result while running the below code,
`q = ('plane fly OR car drive OR cadburys airport -filter:retweets AND filter:replies')`

Its should be probably because of the precedence of AND / OR operators.

You can try some magic with - hypen operator.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Surrounding each keyword/phrase in parenthesis seems to get the results I'm looking for. For example q = '(plane fly) OR (car drive) OR (cadburys chocolate) -filter:retweets AND filter:replies)'. Thanks for taking time out of your day to help!

Answer (score 0):

https://unionmetrics.com/resources/how-to-use-advanced-twitter-search-queries/
According to this link:
You can also chain together multiple keywords to create a more complex query. The OR operator will attach to the word that immediately precedes it, very much like order of operations in algebra. For example, the following query will find tweets that mention social media metrics or social media analytics, because the OR links to the metrics and analytics terms

q="social media metrics OR analytics" would return results containing the words 
social media metrics or social media analytics

You're not wrong, but it was just never clear on how to search for terms longer than 1 word.